# Raspberry Pi Surveilance Cam online

Tags: raspbian, webcam

i've been browsing for days to find how to access live stream of my picam from internet (outside my local network). For stream within local network i already success access the cam from my browser.

how step by step to config my pi, router, and access the live stream from internet
- my router is tp-link mr3420
- i already have the account for no-ip
- stream port from rasppi is 8080

how to be able stream my cam from anywhere?

Answer (score 2):

> how to be able stream my cam from anywhere?

You need a static IP address, which ISP's normally do not provide unless you pay them extra for it.

Your external address -- [you can see it here](http://www.whatsmyip.org/) -- changes dynamically.  In order to reach a service on your router from outside, you need to know this address.  But since it can change, there's no way for you to know what it will be at any given point in time.

Comment: is there anything to do with dynamic dns and also port forwarding?

Comment: Yeah, you can get around it with dynamic DNS.  If it's just you that's using it, you could instead use a simple program on the pi (or any other system on the LAN, since they will all use the same external IP, I believe) to check the address occasionally and write to (e.g.) a dropbox file, or to send you an email whenever it changes.  I don't think it is necessarily that often; it could remain the same for a day or more (you can check on that easily enough).

Comment: Another thing to note is that many routers have dynamic dns support built in, and for the ones that don't have it, you can often flash the router with ddwrt, openwrt, or tomato. I use no-ip's ddns service with my ddwrt router and it works great.